# Reading input one character at a time

Tags: c++, io

For example, given "1912" as input, how do I parse this input and populate an `int a[]` so that it has `a[0]=1`, `a[1]=9` and so on.

If done through a `for` loop it will take `a[0]=1912` and not `a[0]=1`.

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    cin>>a[i];
}
```

Comment: Add the declaration of `a` to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`getchar`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/getchar) to read character by character. Your loop would look like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
  a[i] = getchar();
  a[i] -= '0';
}
```

The return value of `getchar` would be the ascii code for the input character. Since you are trying to read the input in as a digit, you can do that transformation by `a[i] -= '0'`.

Of course, the above loop does not do any input sanitization and assumes you know exactly the format you are reading. You can use `feof` and `ferror` to get for errors.

Comment: a[i] -= '0'; // wat will this line do ?

Comment: I assumed that `a` is an array of `int`s. So, to convert from the character to a digit, you do `a[i]-='0';`.

Comment: You can look at the ascii codes [here](http://www.ascii-code.com/). Let's say the input was "0"(without the quotes). When you do `getchar()`, the return value will be the ascii value of the character '0', which is 30. So, to get the integer `0`, you need to subtract `30` from the result of `getchar()`. Since you don't want to remember ascii codes and since `char` can be implicity converted to `int` with the `int` having its ascii value, you can instead subtract the character `'0'` from the result of `getchar()`.

Comment: sry for bothering again but it outputs -38 in the begning and in the end and i think its because of press of enter. so any way of removing that instead of going over the array and adding condition that if -38 comes skip it and if not enter into the array ?

Comment: No, you cannot remove that input. Another way of doing it would be to simply read in a string, loop over it and convert each character to a digit. This method handles whitespace and newlines automatically. With the `getchar` method, you will have to add a check to see if the input is a digit or not.